# Shell extension on Windows 8.1

Tags: shell, registry, windows-8.1

I wrote a little command-line utility in C++ which I compiled and copied into a location in the system path. I then added the following registry entries. When I right-click a TXT file, the pop-up context menu shows the usual "Open" and "Edit" but also "DoSomething" and "SomethingElse". Selecting either sends the path of the file just clicked to the utility, which processes the file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\cmd2]
@="&DoSomething"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\cmd2\command]
@="DoSomething.exe 0 %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\cmd3]
@="&SomethingElse"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\cmd3\command]
@="DoSomething.exe 1 %1"
```

This works great on Windows XP...but try as I might, I cannot get the context menu entry "DoSomething" to appear on Windows 8.1. And advice on how to modify the registry entries or use another method for 8.1?

Comment: Does Something else appear?

Comment: No, nothing additional appears. It seems the mechanism is different between XP and 8.1, though I can't work out what.